# What does it mean to think of a population as a probability measure?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

I am working independently through parts of Jun Shao's *Mathematical Statistics* after spending a year on Casella and Berger. Most of the measure theory related content is pretty new to me. In the description of "Populations and Samples," page 91-92, Shao states:

> In statistical inference and decision theory, the data set is viewed as a realization or observation of a random element defined on a probability space (Ω,F,P) related to the random experiment. **The probability measure P is called the *population*.** The data set or the random element that produces the data is called a sample from P.

I was hoping someone could offer some intuition around why we would think of a "population" as a "probability measure." It would be helpful if you could offer this explanation in terms of the classical discrete uniform distribution $P(A)=\frac{\#A}{\#S}, A \subseteq S$. How do I think of the measure P(A) as a population (if A represents some event and S represents the sample space)?

Comment: A standard intuitive explanation is the "tickets in a box model": [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tickets+box+model).  Do you need an explanation at some other level of rigor than that?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am familiar with such models and have done plenty of related problems; however, I am not seeing how that illustrates the idea that the measure is the population. Thank you for indicating another direction to search in though; I will look further into it and see if it sheds more light on my question.

Comment: One major point of that model is it uses two things to represent what we intuitively think of as the "population": the tickets in the box *and their relative proportions within it.*  The contents of the box are a physical model of what Shao means by "the probability measure," because of course the measure cannot exist without the underlying space $\Omega$ (which corresponds not to the individual tickets, but to the individual *types* of tickets). You may conceive of the "proportion" as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mathbb{P}$ with respect to the uniform (counting) measure on the tickets.